# Sum of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty q^n \sin(nx)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How to find $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty q^n \sin(nx)$, where $|q|<1$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$? I was thinking about rewriting it as $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (q(\Im(\cos x+i\sin x)))^n$. It is a geometric series with the first term $q \cdot \sin x$, but what is the quotient? I can find $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \sin(nx)$, but how to deal with the imaginary part, when multiplied by $q$?

Thanks!

Comment: Euler to the rescue: $$\sin (nx) = \frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{inx} - e^{-inx}\right).$$

Comment: I think the variable names are a bit confused.  Do you mean $\sum_{n=1}^\infty q^n \sin(nx)$?

Comment: @Argon I edited the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right track. Since $|e^{ix}| = 1$ and $|q| < 1$, $|qe^{ix}| < 1$, so $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty q^n e^{i n x}$ is a geometric series. In particular,
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty q^n e^{i n x} = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty (qe^{ix})^n = qe^{ix} + (qe^{ix})^2 + (qe^{ix})^3 + \cdots = \frac{qe^{ix}}{1 - qe^{i x}}.$$
Now you simply need the imaginary part of the right-hand side, which, if I am not mistaken, is
$$\frac{q \sin x}{1 + q^2 - 2q \cos x}.$$

Observe, also, that
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty q^n \sin(n x) = \frac{q \sin x}{1 + q^2 - 2q \cos x}.$$
is almost the Poisson kernel.

Note: Since
$$a + ar + ar^2 + \cdots = \frac{a}{1 - r}, \quad |r| < 1,$$
we have
$$ar + ar^2 + ar^3 + \cdots = \frac{ar}{1 - r}, \quad |r| < 1.$$
In your case $r = qe^{ix}$ and $a = 1$.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider:

$$\Im \sum_{n=1}^\infty q^n e^{inx}$$

Comment: This is a good, though a rather faint, hint. It most definitely is neither an invalid answer nor a very low-quality one. +1