# The value of $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\left(q\right)^n\left(\sin(na)\right), |q|<1}$

Tags: summation

I need to solve this sum, but unfortunately I have no idea how to start.I would be grateful for every advice.

> $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\left(q\right)^n\left(\sin(na)\right), |q|<1}$$

Comment: Try the Euler formula $\mathrm e^{\mathrm i t} = \cos t + \mathrm i \sin t$.

Comment: This type of question was asked before, did you search before asking?

Comment: Like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1349466/calculating-sum-k-0n-sink-theta?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1172449/find-formula-of-sum-sin-nx?noredirect=1&lq=1) for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty q^n \sin(nx)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714795/sum-of-sum-limits-n-1-infty-qn-sinnx)

Comment: As a general tip, I recommend the use of Approach0 to find duplicates. For example, see what it gives in this case : https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7Dq%5En%5Csin%5Cleft(na%5Cright)%24&p=1

Answer (score 1):

It's the imaginary part of
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^n e^{ina}=\frac1{1-qe^{ia}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

As $\;\sin nt=\operatorname{Im}\mathrm e^{int}$, we have
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(q )^n \sin(na)=\operatorname{Im}\Bigl(\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(q \mathrm e^{it})^n\Bigr).$$
Also, we have
$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } z^n=z\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } z^n=\frac z{1-z},\quad  |z|<1.$$

Answer (score 1):

The complex method is probably the best.
But instead you can: prove by induction on $N$ that
$$
\sum _{n=1}^{N}{q}^{n}\sin \left( na \right) ={\frac {{q}^{N+2}\sin
 \left( Na \right) -{q}^{N+1}\sin \left(  \left( N+1 \right) a
 \right) +q \sin \left( a \right)}{{q}^{2}-2q\cos \left( a \right)+
1}}
$$
and then do the limit easily:
$$
\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}{q}^{n}\sin \left( na \right) = {\frac {q \sin \left( a \right)}{{q}^{2}-2q\cos \left( a \right)+
1}}
$$